# How to make Google custom snippets with custom search?

Tags: google-search, code-snippets

How these [Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?safe=off&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN720IN720&q=w3+&oq=w3+&gs_l=serp.3..0i10i67k1j0i67k1j0i10i67k1j0i67k1l2j0i10i67k1j0j0i67k1j0i10i67k1j0i67k1.7691.8953.0.9195.8.6.0.0.0.0.127.676.1j5.6.0....0...1.1.64.serp..3.5.585.5AvR1-qeQAI) snippets are created for only one site? Also how they
 make the search box? Is this Google search or any other custom search?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are referring to Sitelinks.

**Sitelinks** are provided based on keyword searches where a given site's structure and content is highly relevant to where Google decides to provide additional exposure for the site. There is not any singular adjustment you can make to gain sitelinks. It is outside of your control.

You can strongly increase the likelihood of your site being listed with Sitelinks by improving the quality of your site's architecture along with the quality and quantity of content. Learn more here:

**Source**
 https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en

Comment: does it also apply to the "inner" search bar?

Comment: I found it already. [Here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox).